# How to prevent site collection admin delete his site collection?

Tags: permissions, delete

We need to avoid our users, who are "site owners", delete his site collection by mistake.

The only method I think of is use Jquery to hide/disable the "Delete this site" button. Do we have other way to do so? For example disable the delete site permission. Thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 5):

A WebDeleting event can be used to prevent users event if they are owners to delete a site collection. Example:

```
public override void WebDeleting(SPWebEventProperties properties)
{
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "This site cannot be deleted.";
    properties.Cancel = true;
}
```

See this for more info:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2012/09/07/how-to-prevent-site-deletion-with-a-custom-event-receiver.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to create a [HideCustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms414790%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to hide the "Delete a site" action.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <HideCustomAction
    Id="Customization"
    GroupId = "SiteTasks"
    HideActionId = "DeleteWeb"
    Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings">
 </HideCustomAction>
</Elements>
```

For a list of locations [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730%28v=office.15%29.aspx)